# Getting Type Error With Postman : Cannot destructure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting error when I use postman to sent post request to my backend it gets `TypeError: Cannot destructure property &#39;fullName&#39; of &#39;req.body&#39; as it is undefined`

And the middleware is defined in app.js

app.js:

```
import express from "express"
import cors from "cors"
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser"

const app = express()

app.use(cors({
    origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
    credentials: true
}))

app.use(express.json({limit: "16kb"}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true, limit: "16kb"}))
app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use(cookieParser())

//routes
import userRouter from './routes/user.routes.js'

app.use("/api/v1/users", userRouter) //http://localhoast:4000/api/vi/users/register
export {app}
```

And here is index.js where I have imported the app from app.js:

````
import dotenv from "dotenv"
import connectDB from "./db/index.js";
import {app} from './app.js'

dotenv.config({
    path: './.env'
})
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

connectDB()
.then(()=>{
    app.on("error", (error)=>{
        console.log("Error:", error);
        throw error
    })
    app.listen(port, ()=>{
        console.log(`Listening to Port: ${port}\n Link: http://localhost:${port}`);
    })
})
.catch((error)=>{
    console.log("PostgreSQL Connection Error:", error);
})
```
````

And I am requesting the body in user.controller.js

```
import {asyncHandler} from '../utils/asyncHandler.js'
import {ApiError} from '../utils/apiError.js'
import {ApiResponse} from '../utils/apiResponse.js'
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"
import pg from 'pg'

const registerUser = asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{
    
     console.log("req.body:", req.body);

    const {fullName, email, username, password } = req.body
    console.log("email: ", email,
    "\n fullname: ",fullName,
    "\n username: ",username,
    "\n password: ",password);
    })
export { registerUser}
```

tried consolelogging the output of `req.body`
output of console.log(req.body)

```
req.body: undefined

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'fullName' of 'req.body' as it is undefined.
```

Postman Config:

> Post - http://localhost:6000/api/v1/users/register

> "fullName": "John Doe",

> "email": "john.doe@example.com",

> "password": "John",

> "username": "johndoe123"

Error in postman:`TypeError: Cannot destructure property &#39;fullName&#39; of &#39;req.body&#39; as it is undefined`

Error in console/Terminal" `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'fullName' of 'req.body' as it is undefined.`

AsyncHandler:

```
const asyncHandler = (requestHandler) =>{
    return (res,req,next) =>{
        Promise.resolve(requestHandler(req,res,next)).catch((err)=>next(err))
    }
}

export {asyncHandler}
```

Added Img of postman
[image: postman config]

Comment: why would you want to remove these? No you can't

Comment: I am entirely baffled by _why_ you would not only want to remove `app.use(express.json())` but also your `express` import and `const app = express()`

Comment: What does `app.js` have to do with `index.js`? Neither refers to the other. Why do you have two Express apps? Which file are you actually running to start your server?

Comment: No. Everything required to understand your question needs to be in the question itself. Links to off-site resources may only be used as supplementary material

Comment: Sounds to me, as if you were probably sending a form/urlencoded request, when actually JSON was expected ... or vice versa.

Comment: What is `import {asyncHandler} from '../utils/asyncHandler.js'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was just a simple bug, just had to put `req` before `res`

```js
const asyncHandler = (requestHandler) => {
  return (res, req, next) => { // this to (req, res, next)
    Promise.resolve(requestHandler(req, res, next)).catch((err) => next(err))
  }
}
    
export { asyncHandler }
```